# PL/SQL Record property conditions

Tags: oracle, plsql, while-loop

I have the following record

```
Cursor my_cursor Is Select y, x, z From table Order by y;
my_record my_cursor%rowtype;
```

Knowing that the record `x` property is `null`, am trying to check it against a value in a while loop and am getting the following results:

```
While my_record.x != 'TXT' Loop // loop does not enter
While NVL(my_record.x, '') != 'TXT' Loop // loop does not enter
While NVL(my_record.x, ' ') != 'TXT' Loop // loop enters
```

I was wondering why the first 2 tries are not entering in the loop knowing that when debugging, the return value is true of the expression?

Comment: The first one doesnt evaluate to true when `my_record.x IS NULL`. So is ok not enter. Other two should enter because `{'', ' '} <> 'TXT'`. But doesnt make sense `2)` doesnt enter and `3)` loop enter :/

Comment: See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: because

- `''` is treated as `NULL`
- Oracle uses [Three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) when it compares NULL with values

The condition `NULL != 'TXT'` is neither true nor false. It is unknown.

`NVL(my_record.x, '')` is `NULL` and therefore logical value of `NVL(my_record.x, '') != 'TXT'` is also unknown.

By the way - even NULL is not equal to NULL

You may want to read more from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037)