# Compare String in Oracle Case When

Tags: sql, oracle, case

i have an issue with oracle case when.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '7C54D3E133830A78E040A8C010014B7D' != ''
            THEN '7C54D3E133830A78E040A8C010014B7D'
            WHEN 'e84a4433966c4b8996ce34905acff63d' != ''
            THEN 'e84a4433966c4b8996ce34905acff63d'
            WHEN '7faa9126b1c6412fa58375ab2b2be1db' != ''
            THEN '7faa9126b1c6412fa58375ab2b2be1db'
            ELSE NULL
 END
 FROM DUAL
```

this query always returns null, though it's obvious the result should be the first case. Am i missing something about string comparison in oracle?

Comment: Are you sure you are using this query and/or you are reading the output correctly?

Comment: yes, the output is null.
this  query actually is from an debugged insert query, it always inserts null value, i  am curious why, so i cut it and exe it on select query, it returns null

Comment: Oracle doesn't have *empty string*, but `null`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are checking strings againts an empty string, thus having issues; in Oracle you'd better check if your string `is not null`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '7C54D3E133830A78E040A8C010014B7D' is not null
            THEN '7C54D3E133830A78E040A8C010014B7D'
            WHEN 'e84a4433966c4b8996ce34905acff63d' is not null
            THEN 'e84a4433966c4b8996ce34905acff63d'
            WHEN '7faa9126b1c6412fa58375ab2b2be1db' is not null
            THEN '7faa9126b1c6412fa58375ab2b2be1db'
            ELSE NULL
 END
 FROM DUAL
```

About the way Oracle treats empty string and null, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null) you find something more

An example:

```
select q'['' = '']'         , case when '' = ''            then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all
select q'['' is null]'      , case when '' is null         then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all 
select q'['' = null ]'      , case when '' = null          then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all 
select q'[null = null]'     , case when null = null        then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all 
select q'[null is null]'    , case when null is null       then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all 
select q'['' != '']'        , case when '' != ''           then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all
select q'['' is not null]'  , case when '' is not null     then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all
select q'['' != null ]'     , case when '' != null         then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all
select q'[null != null]'    , case when null != null       then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual union all
select q'[null is not null]', case when null is not null   then 'YES' else 'NO' end from dual
```

gives:

```
'' = ''           NO
'' is null        YES
'' = null         NO
null = null       NO
null is null      YES
'' != ''          NO
'' is not null    NO
'' != null        NO
null != null      NO
null is not null  NO
```

In a word, the only check you can rely on, when talking about `NULL`, is:
 `IS [NOT] NULL`

Comment: Interesting, but is there a reason why the semantics of empty string should be different than a non-empty string?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Great Oracle non sense! So Aleksej is right, so upvote

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: to be honest, I have no idea at all :). I'll simply cite Justin Cave: "I believe the answer is that Oracle is very, very old."

Answer (score 4):

Well, the reason of such a behaviour is that Oracle *doesn't have empty string*, but `null`; that's why

```
   select case when 'abc' != ''  
      ....
```

is actually

```
   select case when 'abc' != null
```

and since `anything != null` is `null` (`true`, `false`, `null` boolean logic) all the `when` don't return `true` and `else` is executed.
The right syntax is

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN '7C54D3E133830A78E040A8C010014B7D' IS NOT NULL
               THEN '7C54D3E133830A78E040A8C010014B7D'
               WHEN 'e84a4433966c4b8996ce34905acff63d' IS NOT NULL
               THEN 'e84a4433966c4b8996ce34905acff63d'
               WHEN '7faa9126b1c6412fa58375ab2b2be1db' IS NOT NULL
               THEN '7faa9126b1c6412fa58375ab2b2be1db'
               ELSE NULL
          END
     FROM DUAL
```