# Case in where clause with column Like condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I'm using a SQL query inside a function. Now I want to pass the parameter value to the SQL where clause only if the param_value is not empty like below.

```
select * 
  from cms_tab 
 where case when param_val <> '' then 
         col1 like '%' || param_val || '%' 
       end
```

How to achieve this?

If the parameter value is not null then I want to fetch records using like (%).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### try this:

```
select * from cms_tab 
where 
param_val is null
 or col1 like '%'||param_val||'%'
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you. I used  " where param_val is null or col1 like '%'||param_val||'%'  "

Comment: `param_val<>''` will always give false

Answer (score 2):

The only safe way to check if a string is "empty" in Oracle is to check if it `IS [NOT] NULL`; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758158/compare-string-in-oracle-case-when/41758235#41758235) you find an example of the issues you can find while checking "empty strings" the wrong way.

Also, `CASE` is not the right choice here; you should better add some boolean logic.

If I understand well, you want to select all the rows if the parameter is "empty" or only the matching rows if the parameter is not "empty"; this could be a way:

```
create or replace procedure testNull ( param_val IN varchar2) is
    vCount number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into vCount
    from cms_tab
    where param_val is null
       or col1 like '%' || param_val || '%' ;
    dbms_output.put_line('vCount = ' || vCount);
end;
```

**Test:**

```
create table cms_tab(col1) as (
    select 'xxx ABC yyy' from dual union all
    select 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' from dual
    )

SQL> exec testNull(null);
vCount = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec testNull('');
vCount = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec testNull('ABC');
vCount = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec testNull('ZZZ');
vCount = 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I expected.