# Return a blank string for a field SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to return a blank string for a field in SQL, even if the field has data?

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, DOB, GENDER, CITY
FROM TABLE
```

I want DOB, to always return blank ''

Comment: we can put the literal string in the SELECT list and give it a column alias, e.g. `SELECT NAME, AGE, ' ' AS DOB, GENDER, CITY FROM TABLE`.  (If we don't need to return the value of the DOB column, then we don't reference the column in the SELECT list.) To return a blank, we need to return a space character `' '`; Oracle interprets a zero length string literal `''` as a NULL value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, an [empty VARCHAR2 is equivalent to a `NULL` value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203536/1509264).

So you can just do:

```
SELECT NAME,
       AGE,
       NULL AS DOB,
       GENDER,
       CITY
FROM   TABLE
```

If you want to give it a specific data type then you can use `CAST`:

```
SELECT NAME,
       AGE,
       CAST( NULL AS DATE ) AS DOB,
       GENDER,
       CITY
FROM   TABLE
```

Comment: I am trying to add a column name but I am getting an error for the null field. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Agent_Sully, try reading the error message. Note: we can't see your computer screen.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, ' ' as DOB, GENDER, CITY
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: A string containing the space character is not the same as an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`NVL2`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm):

```
SELECT NVL2(dob, '', NULL) --rest of cols
FROM TABLE;
```

Please note that `''` is the same as `NULL`. So you have:

```
SELECT '' AS DOB -- rest of cols
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: `NVL2(dob, '', NULL)` is the same as `NVL2(dob, NULL, NULL)` which will always give the output `NULL` - so using `NVL2` is just over-complication.

Comment: @MT0 Yup, that is why there is simple second part. I just wanted to show how to easily compare with `NULL` without using `CASE`.