# nvl ('',col_name) and nvl(null,col_name)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select  col_name1, count(1)
from    tab_name
where   col2 = nvl('', col2)
group by col1;
```

This returns rows in my local DB. But in another server it returns no rows.

But if I replace `nvl('', col2)` with `nvl(null, col2)` it returns the rows.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], including your Oracle version, DDL for your table and DML for you sample data, that demonstrates the problem as [`''` (empty string) is `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203493/1509264) in Oracle and there is no difference between your two queries. I cannot [replicate your issue](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e76e8b/1).

Comment: @MT0 I stand corrected. Prabhu, are you certain you're not actually changing `nvl(' ', col2)` to `nvl(null, col2)`? (Note the space in the string of the first expression).

Comment: '' is not equal to null, instead it is equal to blank.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar It seems [Oracle does things a little differently](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8ece/1/0). (I made the same mistake as you.)