# Plus a value null in oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

In orther language(C#, Sql Server) i see: 1 + null, or '1' + null is null, But in Oracle result is: 1 || null = 1 but '1' + null = null. example:

```
select 1 || null from dual ;
select '1' + null from dual;
```

Result: 1, null

Who can tell me why?

Comment: "But in Oracle result is: 1 || null is null " No it isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle treats `NULL` and the empty string as [the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null?rq=1).

So `1 || NULL` is the same as `1 || ""` (which is `'1'` -- this is string concatenation in SQL, not a logical OR).

For `+` both arguments are converted to numbers, and any arithmetic operation involving `NULL` yields `NULL`.

Comment: But why: select case when null = '' then 1 else 0 end from dual; is 0? if null and "" is the same it will 1?

Comment: @NguoiTotbung - for the same reason `null = null` is false: NULL is **never** equal to anything. That's why SQL language has the `is null` operator (SQL Server has this too).