# Oracle SQL: How to summary value if the value of other attribut is null and summary when is is not valu and then calculated percentage

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  salary table and attribute which employer get extra bonus (yes value).
I want to calculate sum(salary) of employer without exta-bonus and sum of salary with bonus.
Table with attribute  is

```
id   salary     extra_bonus
---  -------    -----------
 1   1200       yes
 2   900
 3   1300
 4   800        yes
 5   1100       yes
```

I want to get report like

```
sumsalary  sumextrabonussalary  percent
---------  -------------------  -------
3100       2100                 67,7%
```

Comment: Check out GROUP BY, and aggregate functions.

Comment: Did you do your math right in your results? Several things don't look right (such as the numbers possible being reversed and the 2100 should be 2200 maybe)?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM( CASE when extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN NULL ELSE salary END ) AS sumsalary,
       SUM( CASE when extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN salary END ) AS sumextrabonussalary,
       SUM( CASE when extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN NULL ELSE salary END )
       / SUM( CASE when extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN salary END )
       * 100 AS percent
FROM   your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've worked with Oracle, but I believe that this should work:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN 0 ELSE salary END) As sumsalary,
    SUM(CASE WHEN extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN salary ELSE 0 END) AS sumextrabonussalary,
    SUM(CASE WHEN extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN salary ELSE 0 END)/
    SUM(CASE WHEN extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN 0 ELSE salary END) AS percent
FROM
    My_Table
```

Comment: `NULL <> 'yes'` does not evaluate to true - it evaluates to `NULL`; so your `sumsalary` value will always be 0.

Comment: It only evaluates to NULL if it has a value of NULL. If it has a value of empty string (which is what it looks like to me in the OP) then it will evaluate to true or false appropriately. You are correct that I should have pointed that out though since the OP is a bit unclear.

Comment: [Oracle treats empty strings as `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203493/1509264).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that. Silly database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation and subquery behind `FROM`

```
 SELECT sumsalary, sumextrabonussalary, sumsalary / sumextrabonussalary * 100 as Percent
 FROM
 (
   SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN extra_bonus IS NULL THEN salary END ) AS sumsalary,
          SUM( CASE WHEN extra_bonus = 'yes' THEN salary END ) AS sumextrabonussalary
   FROM yourtable
 ) t
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156363/discussion-between-radim-baca-and-xing).

Comment: Hi, works also this conditional aggregation behind FROM, Thx