# Random sorting with ORDER BY with CASE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am testing ORDER BY clause with CASE, and came across this problem.

My test select statement:

```
SELECT to_date as "One", field1 as "Two"
   FROM(
        SELECT to_date('yyyy-mm-dd', '2017-10-10'), '333' union all
        SELECT to_date('yyyy-mm-dd', '2017-09-09'), '111' union all
        SELECT to_date('yyyy-mm-dd', '2017-09-09'), '222' union all
        SELECT to_date('yyyy-mm-dd', '2017-09-09'), '' union all
        SELECT to_date('yyyy-mm-dd', '2017-09-09'), ''
        )
   ORDER BY One DESC,
          CASE when Two = '' then 1 
               else 0 end DESC
```

And it's result may vary in a way, that sorting by second column is random:
[image]
[image]

How should I modify CASE clause to avoid it?

Comment: @YogeshSharma done

Comment: @YogeshSharma my bad, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the column `two` as third order condition

```
ORDER BY One DESC,
         CASE when Two = '' then 1 else 0 end DESC,
         Two DESC
```

The second order condition only puts empty entries first and not more.

Comment: thank you, it works! so, "else 0" part means just to ignore any other value?

Comment: The `case` results in 2 values: 0 or 1. You sort by that. This means 1-values come first in the list and then all 0-values.

Comment: @MichaelBobryashov The `CASE` expression, here, will always evaluate to `0` so this `ORDER BY` clause is the equivalent of `ORDER BY One DESC, Two DESC` and the [default is for `DESC` ordering to be `NULLS FIRST`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2171079) (the `CASE` expression is useless).

Comment: The explanation of why this works is entirely wrong!

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, an [empty string `''` is the identical to `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null) so your query is:

```
ORDER BY
  One DESC,
  CASE when Two = NULL then 1 else 0 end DESC
```

When comparing values, the are possible states are:

```
Equality                 Result
------------------------ ------
value = value            TRUE
value = other_value      FALSE
value = NULL             NULL
NULL  = NULL             NULL
```

Your `CASE` expression will only evaluate to `1` when the equality evaluates to `TRUE` and this will never be the result when at least one side of the equality is `NULL`.

What you want is to use `IS NULL` rather than `= ''`:

```
ORDER BY
  One DESC,
  CASE WHEN Two IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
  Two DESC;
```

Which you can simplify to:

```
ORDER BY
  One DESC,
  Two DESC NULLS FIRST;
```

The default for `DESC` ordering is `NULLS FIRST` so you *could* further simplify it to:

```
ORDER BY
  One DESC,
  Two DESC;
```

However, I would not take it this far as you are better explicitly stating that you are expecting `NULL` values to be ordered before non-`NULL` so future developers know that that is your intended ordering (rather than just an unintentional side-effect of your query).

Comment: thanks for clarification. do you know if that applies to denodo's VQL as well?

Comment: @MichaelBobryashov No idea as I have never used Denodo - if you need an answer to that then you can see if you can find it in their documentation or ask it as a new question with the appropriate tags (so that Denodo experts can answer it).