# How can I handle null values in an INSERT with JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I'm trying to execute an insert operation to an Oracle DB Table from Java with JPA.
The following is my code:

```
String coCode;
String coDescription;

/* some operations on data ... */

String queryStatement = 
  "insert into MANAGER_DATA (CO_CODE, CO_DESCRIPTION) values (?1, ?2)";

Query updateQuery = getEntityManager(context).createNativeQuery(queryStatement);

updateQuery.setParameter(1, coCode);
updateQuery.setParameter(2, coDescription.compareTo("") == 0 ? null : coDescription);

updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```

The problem is that `coDescription` can be null in case of an empty String and, in that case, I want the null value to be added in the table as well (`coCode` is primary key but `coDescription` is nullable). Apparently I cannot pass a `null` value to the `setParameter` function directly, as I am doing above.

How can I solve this and allow the null value to be added to my DB table?

Comment: ASFAIK It is possible to pass null values as second argument in `setParameter` method since Hibernate 5 (I tested it on 5.0.2), try upgrade your dependencies it should solve your problem.

Comment: Why would you use JPA for doing basic inserts? you could have a class that maps to that table and insert an object if using JPA was so critical to you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be using old Hibernate version affected by [HHH-9165 createNativeQuery's setParameter does not support null](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9165) bug. Upgrade to Hibernate 5.0.2 or newer to resolve it. As per mentioned Jira:

> Just tested it with Hibernate 5.0.2 and the bug seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle evaluates empty strings as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null).

For example:

```
insert into MANAGER_DATA (CO_CODE, CO_DESCRIPTION) values ('my_code', '')
```

will insert this row: ('my_code', null).

Therefore you can leave it empty string.