# Coalesce(null,'') gets null in Oracle and gets '' in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

- Oracle version : 12.1.0.2.0
- SQL Server version : 2012

My code:

```
select COALESCE (null, '') 
from dual
```

in Oracle returns `null` result, but

```
select COALESCE (null, '')
```

in SQL Server returns a `''` result.

Why did this result differ?

They are ANSI standards, shouldn't it be the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Oracle document about [NULL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037)

> Oracle Database treats a character value with a length of zero as null.

Oracle internally changes the empty string to `NULL` values. Oracle simply won't let insert an empty string.

```
select null from dual
```

the same as

```
select '' from dual
```

They are all return `NULL`.

So when you use `select COALESCE (null,'')  from dual` it will translate to `select COALESCE (null,null) from dual` in Oracle.

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/VILZ99378)

Here is a link talk about this.

[Why does Oracle 9i treat an empty string as NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037):

> Oracle Database treats a character value with a length of zero as null.

Which is not ANSI standard.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning a zero-length string to a field results in `NULL` when dealing with a variable-length character type (e.g. `VARCHAR` or `VARCHAR2`). However, when a zero-length string is assigned to a fixed-length character type (e.g. `CHAR`) the result is that the field is blank-padded to full defined length, as required for the `CHAR` data type. [See this AskTom question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5984520277372) for further info.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following code in Oracle and SQL Server:

```
select COALESCE (null,' ') from dual
select COALESCE (null,' ')
```

it returns `not null` result in both Oracle and SQL Server

The main issue is how Oracle and SQL Server treat the 2nd expression  `''`. In Oracle, it is treated as `NULL` but SQL Server treats it as an empty space.

Comment: I wouldn't call that `parameter`.. `Expression` to be precise