# Is '' and null are same in Oracle or different

Tags: oracle

PRODUCTS Table having column id and name.

```
insert into PRODUCTS(id,name)
values(1,'');

insert into PRODUCTS(id,name)
values(2,null);

insert into PRODUCTS(id,name)
values(1,'product1');

==========================
ID    Name
1     (null)
2     (null)
3     product1
```

so my question is:

1. Can we fetch the row having name as ''?
2. Can we fetch the row having name as null?
3. Is '' and null in oracle same?
4. Can we differentiate between these 2 ('' and null) in oracle
   package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well did you run any tests to see for yourself?

Comment: I tried running below query
select * from PRODUCTS where trim(NAME) ='' or NAME='';
select * from PRODUCTS NAME is null;

Comment: [Oracle Database treats a character value with a length of zero as null.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Nulls.html) So - sort of (with `is null`); yes (also with `is null`); yes; and no. You can't use `=`. (Also be aware of padded and non-padded character semantics...)

Comment: This could perhaps be considered a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203493/266304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your questions:

1. Can we fetch the row having name as ''?

> Yes: `select * from products where name is null;`

2. Can we fetch the row having name as null?

> Yes: `select * from products where name is null;`

3. Is '' and null in oracle same?

> Yes, Oracle does not make any difference between '' (empty string) and null.

4. Can we differentiate between these 2 ('' and null) in oracle package?

> No. (afaik)